# Flask Internal server error : How to handle request to server when posting form data to extract value from form correctly?

Tags: python, flask

I've got an app, frontend is React, and backend is Flask with a single `app.py` file. After I try to submit the form using a post request, I get an `internal server error 500` in my JS console and in the terminal it says: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'`.
This error arises after I click the submit button of the form. So it looks like the backend is not handling the request correctly.

I've tried restarting my flask server and I've added CORS to the app. I will post frontend code as well in case that helps to show context.

I guess I'm just wondering if my backend code is correctly handling the request to extract the value `inputText` from the textarea part of the form, or if something else is amiss? Is it reaching the server at all?

**The app.py code:**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
CORS(app)

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def result():
        text = request.form.get('inputText')
        upper_text = text.upper()
        print(upper_text)

        return upper_text
```

I set proxy: "http://localhost:5000" in package.json.

**React Form Component code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import DisplayUpper from './DisplayUpper';


function Form() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState("");
  const [isSubmitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
   setSubmitted(true)
    
    console.log("button clicked");

    const config = {
      headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
 

     };

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/process", {
        inputText: inputText,
      }, config)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("res", res);
        setFetchedData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((er) => {
        console.log(er);
      });
      
    }

    
  return (
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post">
      <label>
        Enter Text :
        <TextField multiline={true} variant="outlined"
          name="inputText"
          value={inputText}
          onChange={(e) => setInputText(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit" name="Submit">
        SUBMIT
      </Button>
    </form>
{isSubmitted && <DisplayUpper/>}
    </div> 
    );
    }


export default Form;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case axois is sending json data, so to access that data you can use `request.json` (instead of `request.form`). Once you replace `request.form` with `request.json` the code should work.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't fix it. I did text= request.json('inputText').

Comment: what do you mean, do you mean that that request.json('inputText') didn't work, or that did (it's supposed be request.json.get('inputText') )

Comment: THANK YOU SO much! I did request.json.get('inputText') ) and it's working. I am so grateful to you. Was stuck on this for days. Can you tell me, if you have time, why request.form.get('inputText') didn't work? I thought it would be picking up inputText from the form when I make the axios call? When would you use request.form instead? In any case, thank you again. Wish you all the best.

Comment: Your welcome! With http requests they can have different content types, axois sends json by default (I believe it *can* send form data), request.form would be used for html forms, or form content types.